# Como abrir o bloco de notas com conteúdo dentro sem salvar?

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber como abro o bloco de notas utilizando C#, com conteúdo gerado através de uma *string*, porém não quero que fique salvo em nenhum lugar.

Comment: Estou utilizando o Visual Studio, sou novato em C#, até então eu estou utilizando o Process.Start("notepad.exe") para abrir o bloco de nota, porem quero que apareça o conteúdo.

Comment: Dicas de link dadas pelo usuário @AndersonCarlosWoss no [chat da rede](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha), para vc avaliar se tem algo que ajude https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613576/ e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552671/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para você abrir o notepad e escrever algum texto nele você precisa executar o processo do notepad e depois utilizar algumas funcionalidades do Windows.

Primeiramente importe esses dois métodos para sua classe:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
```

Agora você irá implementar um método que irá utilizar essa funcionalidades do Windows para executar o que deseja:

```
public void EscreverNotepad(string texto)
{
    Process.Start("notepad.exe");
    Process[] notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

    if (notepad.Length == 0)
        return;

    if (notepad[0] != null)
    {
        IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepad[0].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
        SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, texto);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Porque não criar o ficheiro na temporária do utilizador e depois apagá-lo?

```
private void CreateTempFile()
{
    string strTempFile = $"{Path.GetTempPath()}{Path.GetRandomFileName()}.txt";

    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strTempFile))
            sw.WriteLine("ola mundo");

        Process process = Process.Start(strTempFile);

        // aguardar que o processo conclua o loading
        process.WaitForInputIdle();
        // esperar que o processo feche
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (File.Exists(strTempFile))
            File.Delete(strTempFile);
    }
}
```